# Show the units in $\operatorname{End}(R)$ is $\operatorname{Aut}(R)$, the group of additive group automorphisms of R.

Tags: ring-theory

having difficulty showing that the units of $$\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z}(R) = \{f\colon R \rightarrow R\mid f\text{ an additive group homomorphism}\}$$ equals the $\operatorname{Aut}(R)$.

Comment: Does the subscript $Z$ denote the integers?

Comment: Yea it does denote the integers.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited again to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should follow almost immediately from the definitions:

An automorphism $f \in \text{Aut}(R)$ is, by definition, something that has a two-sided inverse, and so, by definition again, it is a unit.

On the other hand, an element $g$ is a unit if it has a two-sided inverse, namely an element $g^{-1}$ such that $g \circ g^{-1} = \text{id} = g^{-1} \circ g$. But then $g$ must be an automorphism also, by definition.

Hence the units in $\text{End}(R)$ are precisely the automorphisms.